# Django model formset query generates extra object

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a formset of confirmation models. I've succesfully created the formset however formset creates an extra confirmation object.

Here is my code:

**VIEW**

```
def render_fulfillment_modal(request,template='test.html'):
    ....
    formset = modelformset_factory(Confirmation)
    form = formset(queryset=Confirmation.objects.filter(customer_order__deal = deal))

   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url open_fullfill_modal deal.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.management_form }}                  
      {% for f in form %}       
      <tr>
      <td>{{f.fullfilled}}</td>                                 
      <td>
      <p class="name">{{f.instance|confirmation_user_info}}</p>                                  
      </td>                     
      <td><input type="text" class="input-small datepicker"></td>
      <td>{{f.tracking_code}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}

     <div class="pull-right button-box"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Save Changes</button>
     </div>
```

I'm getting an extra form for unrelated object which is not in my queryset. I've tried this with another models and each time I'm getting an extra object. I suppose it's something with the formsets to handle data or something, I'm not sure. The problem occurs when I post this form. It gives me MultiValueDictKeyError which is :

```
"Key 'form-0-id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'3'] ...
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

Just put a `{{f.id}}` before `{{f.fullfilled}}`

It's given a hidden form-id for all f, and pass it to QueryDict in request.Post

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the definition of `modelformset_factory` below ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory)) the `extra` parameter defaults to 1, which creates the extra object you mentioned.

```
modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None, formset=BaseModelFormSet, extra=1, can_delete=False, can_order=False, max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None, widgets=None, validate_max=False, localized_fields=None, labels=None, help_texts=None, error_messages=None, min_num=None, validate_min=False, field_classes=None, absolute_max=None, can_delete_extra=True)
```

So all you need to pass `extra=0` to the formset:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(Confirmation, extra=0)
```

From Django docs: [Limiting the number of editable objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects)

> As with regular formsets, you can use the max_num and extra parameters to modelformset_factory() to limit the number of extra forms displayed.

Comment: Providing a link to django docs is not very reliable as the docs can change at any time. Could you also explain in you answer on why we need this extra prop?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explanation and quotes from Django docs, but I kept the links in case someone needs them. @SimasJoneliunas