# cant get an id to be added to a django formset

Tags: django, forms, formsets

im getting an error when trying to POST a form, which doesn't make much sense.

the error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/courses/course-selector/add/
"Key 'form-0-id' not found in <QueryDict:
```

so i've done the googling and worked out that because i'm drawing the form myself (I'd built a table and printed out each field in the place i wanted it).

so I've tried to add in a field with the id and it doesn't print. it just doesn't have an id in the template for me to write into the form. im not sure what to do now cos the established advice for this case in google i've followed and found an issue.

the template code.

```
<form action="." method="POST" id="formset">
<table>
    <tr>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        {% for field in formset.forms.0 %}
            {% if not field.is_hidden %}
                <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>

    {% for f in formset.forms %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{ f.id }}" /></td>
            <td>{{ f.id }}</td>
            {% for field in f %}
                {% if not field.is_hidden %}
                    <td>
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% else %}
                    <td valign="bottom">{{ field }}</
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

   </table>
</form>
```

snipped for brevity...

why doesn't {{ f.id }} output anything.

edit1
adding in the code that generates the formset, it might be why im not getting an id.

```
            InstanceFormSet = formset_factory(BulkAddInstanceForm, extra=0)
            # build the list for populating the forms
            n, datalist = 0, []
            while n < int(input_data['copies']):
                datalist.append(data)
                n +=1
            formset = InstanceFormSet(initial=datalist)
```

Comment: hmmm, stupid question maybe, is this because the formset is based on a form which doesn't have an id field? or should the id be generated automatically?

Comment: What is `f.id` supposed to be? A field?

Comment: f is the form so f.id is the id of the form. hence asking if the formset generates an id for the form. will add in the generation of the formset to clear this up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611232/django-model-formset-query-generates-extra-object found this exact same issue on this lined question, but his resolution isnt working for me. i should add we're on django 1.3 so is it that an id was added to forms within a formset in 1.4?

Comment: I still don't understand why you think a form should have an `id` attribute. It's not something a form has by default, which is why I asked if you've defined a field called `id`.

Comment: thats not quite what you asked me...

read the code example here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/#manually-rendered-can-delete-and-can-order

thats why i thought when building a formset the forms got an id.

Answer (score 0):

i've found multiple errors in your template:

1. you are iterating over all forms in the formset but you are also displaying all non hidden fields of the first form. this means you have duplicated fields
2. later you are iterating over all fields in all forms. but you are also displaying the id field twice. once as a field and one as part of the checkbox id. if the form doesn't have an id field it does not output anything as f.id

Comment: 1. not sure how i've duplicated anything?
2. i know this. this code is me trying to work out if its a variable or a full blown field. its neither, it doesn't exist.

Comment: you get form 0 like this `{% for field in formset.forms.0 %}` and later you iterate over all forms `{% for f in formset.forms %}` which includes form 0

Comment: im getting a form 0 and a form 1 (when i choose to have more than one form) but I'm not getting an id with my forms... i suppose my question boils down to whether or not i should have an id built into a form as part of a formset or whether or not i have to manually create it.

Answer (score 0):

I use {{forloop.counter0}} or {{forloop.counter}}
 to work out what the id for the form in the formset should be

Answer (score 0):

A few years late to the game, but this is the answer. Put this under `{% for f in formset.forms %}`

```
{{ forloop.counter }}
```

This will output the number associated with each form (eg. 1, 2, 3, etc.)